# XML Bean reference learning

Tags: java, xml, spring-mvc, batch-processing, dao

I am going through someone elses application context file in our Java Spring application code and trying to figure out what is going on. A property reference's something that does not appear to exist.

EX.

```
<bean id="translator" class="com.xyz.batch.manager.123.BatchTranslator">
    <property name= "tobDao" ref="JDAOTobLineRecord" />
    <property name= "bibDao" ref="JDAOBibLineRecord" />
    <property name= "jeeDao" ref="JDAOJeeLineRecord" />
</bean>
```

now when i search the entire project i get no matches for JDAOTobLineRecord, JDAOBibLineRecord, or JDAOJeeLineRecord. However there are classes TobLineRecord, BibLineRecord, and JeeLineRecord which are database references. Also tobDao, bibDao, and jeeDao are DAO objects in the java class BatchTranslator. What is the ref doing?

Comment: If they end up being something other than null then chances are they're defined *somewhere*, somehow.

Comment: but if I searched the entire project, where is left? how could I find where they are defined?

Comment: Annotations, Java or Groovy config, additional XML config files, etc. There may be something buried in your code or a support library that does things automatically, who knows.

Comment: well thanks for your input. Unfortunately i need to add an additional property name and reference into the bean and hopping it somehow just works, haha, like that would ever happen.